# Need help in understanding perl tr command with /d

Tags: perl, translate

I came across the following Perl example on the web.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

$string = 'the cat sat on the mat.';
$string =~ tr/a-z/b/d;

print "$string\n";
```

result:

```
b b   b.
```

Can someone please explain how ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/d` denotes `delete`.

It's quite unusual to do a `tr` like that because it's confusing.

```
tr/a-z//d
```

would delete all 'a-z' characters.

```
tr/a-z/b/
```

would transliterate all `a-z` characters to `b`.

What's happening here though is - because your transliteration doesn't map an equal number of character on each side - anything that *doesn't* map is deleted.

So what you're effectively doing is:

```
tr/b-z//d;
tr/a/b/;
```

E.g. transliterating all the `a`s to `b`s and then deleting anything else (except spaces and dots).

To illustrate:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = 'the cat sat on the mat.';
$string =~ tr/the/xyz/d;

print "$string\n";
```

Warns:

```
Useless use of /d modifier in transliteration operator at line 5.
```

and prints:

```
xyz cax sax on xyz max.
```

If you change that to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = 'the cat sat on the mat.';
$string =~ tr/the/xy/d;

print "$string\n";
```

You get instead:

```
xy cax sax on xy max.
```

And thus: `t` -> `x` and `h` -> `y`. `e` just gets deleted.

Comment: great!. Thanks a lot Sobrique for this detail explanation. Appreciate your quick help.

Answer (score 3):

`d` is used to delete found but not replaced characters.

To remove the characters which are not in the matching list can be done by appending `d` to the end of the [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html) operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my $string = 'my name is serenesat';
$string =~ tr/a-z/bcd/d;
print "$string\n";
```

Prints:

```
 b  b
```

Not matching characters in the string is removed, and only the matching character replaced (`a` replaced with `b`).

Comment: thank you serenesat for the quick help. As sobrique explained i was unaware of the effective result of tr/b-z//d;
tr/a/b/;